# DROPBOX api in mvc application

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I have search a lot but not got answer anywhere that how i can use DROPBOX api in my mvc application.Is it Possible to Upload files from dropbox api.if yes 
Please suggest me api and good code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can look this page. There is no official support for .NET in dropbox api, but third party libraries supplies that.

[DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/other)

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at our v2 API (currently in preview), for which an official .NET SDK exists. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers-preview/documentation/c-sharp.